# Passing parameters to/from JavaScript & Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

In my Rails app I have a helper method **`location`** that gets the coordinates for a given IP address and makes them available across all controllers and views. For example **`location.latitude`** returns the latitude of the user. You get the idea.

I also have some Javascript that draws a Map from the Google Maps API based upon a given lat/lon pair. The problem is that I have no idea how to pass the **`location`** params into the JavaScript!

The JavaScript resides in 'application.js' and looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
  { 

    //Map options...I want the params to go into the var 'MapOptions' below

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.764698,-73.978972),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    //Setup and Draw the Map...
    //....................................
  };
```

The map itself gets called in the HTML like so. There isn't an obvious way to pass params.

```
<div id="map_canvas">
  <!-- The Map gets drawn here! -->
</div>
```

I know this is probably an obvious question, but I've never had to pass a parameter from my application to Javascript this way before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [data attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) work well here.

html

```
<div id="map_canvas" data-latitude="40.764698" data-longitude="-73.978972">
  <!-- The Map gets drawn here! -->
</div>
```

or with your helpers

```
<div id="map_canvas" data-latitude="<%= location.latitude %>" data-longitude="<%= location.longitude %>">
  <!-- The Map gets drawn here! -->
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  //Map options...I want the params to go into the var 'MapOptions' below

  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = $('#map_canvas');
    var lat = mapDiv.data('latitude'),
        lng = mapDiv.data('longitude');

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

  //Setup and Draw the Map...
  //....................................
};
```

Comment: Hey Joe! Greet meeting you the other night! JavaScript is probably my weakest point, as I only just started doing front-end out of necessity. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign lat and long to the hidden fields in the view. And in your applicatons.js script just get them like `$("#lat").val()` Not the ultimate solution, but should work well.

Answer (score 1):

Passing data into javascript can be simplified with the help of Gon gem 
For example, define anything with *gon* in your controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def show_map
    #....
    gon.mapLatLong = [40.764698,-73.978972]
```

Next, output this erb tag in your view

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

The *gon* values defined in that controller will be change into javascript variables in your views.
Thus, you can write it like this in your javascript

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(gon.mapLatLong[0],gon.mapLatLong[1]),
```

reference:
https://github.com/gazay/gon
http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `center: new google.maps.LatLng(gon.mapLatLong[0],gon.mapLatLong[1]),`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following page that explains how to pass data to JavaScript:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

In short, just use:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
   window.productsURL = '<%= j products_url %>';
<% end %>
```

And then refer to productsURL anywhere in your scripts.