# Call ruby method from JavaScript or pass parametr from view in RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have view with list of websites. Details about websites are shown in retracted mode.

I need to show appropriate website details, when user clicks on some image.

I was using this post : [Passing parameters to/from JavaScript & Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272147/passing-parameters-to-from-javascript-rails)

Here is my code from view:

```
 <table>
   <% @websites.each do |website| %>
  <%if (current_user.id == website.user_id)%>
  <tr>
    <td>  <%= link_to(image_tag("/images/caret-horizontal.png",website_path(website)) %> </td>
<td>  
<h4><%= website.name %></h4> </td>

 </tr>
 <table id="<%= website.id %>">
 <tr >
   <td >
  <td >
  <%= website.url %>
  </td>
  </td>
</tr>
 <tr id="<%= website.id %>">
<td >
<td >
<%= website.category  %>
</td>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="<%= website.id %>">
 <td>
<td><%= website.language %></td>
 </td>
```

```
<%end%>

 <%end%>
 </table>
```

And code in application.js:

```
   $("#table").show();//here I need something like var table = <%= website.id%>
```

How I should choose appropriate website id?

or I should transmit website.id in data ?

How I can do it another way ?

Answer (score 1):

There is such a great tutorial about this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript
This tutorial provides you a few ways to pass data from rails to your js. :)

Anyway, change your table id to any value, and add data-id to your table

```
<table id="table-data" data-id="<%= website.id %>">
```

and now you can get the value:

```
var yourWebsiteId = $("#table-data").attr("data-id");
```

Comment: Yes, try it I'm sure you can do that. I used to face the same problem as you too, and this tutorial could help me. :)

Comment: why do you need gon.website? why not just `@website = Website.find(params[:id])?`

Comment: Sorry for my stupid questions and acknowledges, but how I can pass it in js

Comment: Oh! so you don't get it from this tutorial yet. let's me edit my answer

Comment: So I should put condition : 
If ($("#table-data").data('id')==yourWebsiteId) $("#caret-horizontal").click(function(){
$("#table-data").show();
?

Comment: Thank you for help!
Ok, I will create new question) 
For now it's opening only first table.